# Make a rectangle around a sprite in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Hi sorry for repeating this question but i cant figure out what am i doing wrong .. i am a noob in cocos2d ...

here is my header file:

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Mice.h"
// HelloWorld Layer
@interface PlayScreen : CCLayerColor
{

enter code here
Mice *mice ;
CGRect screenSize;

CCSprite *background ;
CCSprite *objectsBoundry;
CCSprite *scoreBoundry ;

}
```

// returns a Scene that contains the HelloWorld as the only child

```
+(id) scene;
@property (retain,nonatomic)Mice *mice;
@property (retain,nonatomic)CCSprite *background;
@property (retain,nonatomic)CCSprite *objectsBoundary;
@property (retain,nonatomic)CCSprite *scoreBoundary;


- (void)rotateEnemy:(Mice *) pSprite;
- (CGRect)rectMake ;
@end
```

and this is my implementation file

```
-(id)init{
if( (self=[super init] )) {
    mice = [Mice spriteWithFile:@"mice.png" ];
    CGRect * micerec = [mice rectMake];//gives an error here that mice may not respond //to method rectMake

}
    return self;
}

-(CGRect)rectMake {

    CGRect aRect = CGRectMake((self.position.x-self.contentSize.width/2),
                          (self.position.y-self.contentSize.height/2),
                          self.contentSize.width,self.contentSize.height);


return aRect;
}
```

dont get whats wrong .. thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rectMake method is not within your Mice class. That's your problem. Also here's a better rect method modified from CCMenuItem:

```
-(CGRect) rect
{
    return CGRectMake(position.x - contentSize.width*anchorPoint.x,
                      position.y - contentSize.height*anchorPoint.y,
                      contentSize.width, contentSize.height);   
}
```

Ensure CCSprite.contentSize isn't empty. Example of how that happens: You use a CCSprite, but add the actual content is displayed in a child of that CCSprite.